# What does this logcat line mean

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am seeing this logcat line when I run my app.

```
/dalvikvm(20160): 20160(com.test) stat: (e)  315  4699KB / (c)    0     0KB / (a)    1  5355KB / (h)  2836KB  6884KB  4047KB
```

My application runs ok, dont see any issue, but this red line in logcat worries me. stat(e) looks like some kind of error statistics. I am just guessing. I did some googling, but could not find anything

Comment: Don't worry man, everything's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about, it just simple Dalvik VM waste. Anyway as a usual developer you couldn't make any affect on it.